# Switching out array sizes in 2d array takes different amount of memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array

I declared a 2d-array matrix in Java of type byte. When checking the memory used with the dimensions (10^6 x 4) it was drastically different from the same size matrix but with dimensions (4 x 10^6).

```
// Measure memory before matrix initialization -> 2MB
System.out.println("Meg used="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-
 Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1000*1000)+"M");

byte[][] test = new byte[4][1000000]; // init

// Measuring memory after -> 6MB as expected
System.out.println("Meg used="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-
 Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1000*1000)+"M");
```

```
// Measure memory before matrix initialization -> 2MB
System.out.println("Meg used="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-
 Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1000*1000)+"M");

byte[][] test = new byte[1000000][4]; // init

// Measuring memory after -> 30MB
System.out.println("Meg used="+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-
 Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1000*1000)+"M");
```

In the first case I get 6MB so the array takes 4MB as expected. However in the second case the matrix takes 28MB. Why are they not equal?

Comment: As a follow up, is it possible to declare the matrix as in the second case but still only use 4MB?

Comment: Quite an interesting question, I found this article
http://ipalopezhentsev.github.io/java/c%23/memory/2014/08/07/multidim-arrays-memory/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the overhead that makes the difference. For every array Java has to save information. It's just 4 long arrays vs. 1000000 short arrays.